# How can I increase the size of integral inside tikz and the length of the arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,scopes}
%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzstyle{labeled}=[execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$]
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
    \node[on chain] {$\int \cos^3(2x) dx$};
    \node[on chain, join={node[above]
          {$dx \leftarrow \frac{1}{2} d2x$}}] {$\int \cos^3(2x) \frac{1}{2} d2x$} ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
$$
\int \cos^3(2x) dx
$$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

1. How can I make the integral symbol bigger in tikz picture?
2. How can I make the arrow, that shows the transformation to auto-adjust it's length to the size of the expression above it? Currently it's much shorter, making the text overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution (using `\displaystyle` to make a bigger integral symbol and using `node distance=2cm` to enlarge the arrow).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,scopes}
%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzstyle{labeled}=[execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$]
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=2cm] {
    \node[on chain] {$\displaystyle\int \cos^3(2x) dx$};
    \node[on chain, join={node[above]
          {$dx \leftarrow \frac{1}{2} d2x$}}] {$\displaystyle\int \cos^3(2x) \frac{1}{2} d2x$} ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\[
\int \cos^3(2x) dx
\]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** here is a solution with "auto adjustable" arrow (using `\widthof` from calc package).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,scopes}
%
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  join/.style={
    after node path={%
      \ifx%
      \tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty%
      \else
      (\tikzchainprevious)%
      edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)
      \fi
    },
  },
}
\makeatother
%
\newlength{\mylen}
\tikzset{
  >=stealth',
  every on chain/.append style={join},
  every join/.style={->},
  join with arrow/.code={
    \setlength{\mylen}{\widthof{#1}}
    \tikzset{node distance=\mylen,on chain,join={node[above]{#1}}}
  },
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
    \node[on chain] {$\displaystyle\int \cos^3(2x) dx$};
    \node[join with arrow={$dx \leftarrow \frac{1}{2} d2x$}]
    {$\displaystyle\int \cos^3(2x) \frac{1}{2} d2x$} ;
    \node[join with arrow={???}]
    {$\displaystyle\int \cos^3(2x) \frac{1}{2} d2x$} ;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\[
\int \cos^3(2x) dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the arrow auto adjustable? Because I will have a chain of such transformations and the text at the top will always have different width.

Comment: @user4035 I edited my answer...

Comment: @user4035 Since I edited my answer, you may remove all your comments about the last line missing in the second example... ;-)

Comment: " you may remove all your comments about the last line" - Done